# One or more songs?

Tags: greek, matthew

> “And when they had sung a hymn, they went out to the Mount of Olives.”
> ‭‭Matthew‬ ‭26:30‬ ‭

The English and other translations say a, singular, song was sung but doesn’t the Greek υμνησαντες say it’s plural?

> και υμνησαντες εξηλθον εις το ορος των ελαιων

Is there a reason this is translated as singular?

And if it is just one which of the Hallel songs was the last one they sang? Psalm 118 or 136 or another? Can we know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that the verb ὑμνήσαντες is plural - but that plurality of the verb refers to its subject and not its object.  Thus one might translate Matt 26:30 as

> and they sang [and] went out to the mount of olives

The implied subject of both verbs ὑμνήσαντες and ἐξῆλθον is "they", ie, the disciples and Jesus.  What hymn or Psalm they sang is not stated but tradition usually meant that it might have been one or more of Ps 113-118.

The verb ὑμνέω = to sing or sing a hymn of praise has come directly into English as the word "hymn".  The verb is used only in four places, Matt 26:30, Mark 14:26, Acts 16:25, Heb 2:12.

Comment: I think I share your view, just wanted a second opinion. Thank you